# Background gradient combined with an image on every page

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, background-color, android-xml

Is there a way to make a xml file with a gradient for the background of my app and at the same time put the logo in it.

So when I set the background of my layout, I get the gradient with my logo on it.

Ofcourse it is possible to just define the gradient and on every page drop the logo on it, but isn't the way I want to accomplish beter?

I tried combining both in a xml file, but that didn't work out and crashed the app.

Gradient created by xml and logo is an image 1 one xml file and use it on every page. When I change the logo in background.xml I need it to change on every other page.

I'd like to use the following xml as an background for all my layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:endColor="#008d36"
    android:gradientRadius="326"
    android:type="radial"/>
</shape>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to give a gradient from XML layout.

But in your scenario you want to put the Gradient for logo?

Give the brief description of your requirement.

Make the drawable folder in res and create the xml name is gradient.xml and copy these code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:endColor="#008d36"
    android:gradientRadius="326"
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:type="radial" />

</shape>
```

Also right these code in your main layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/yourlogoimage" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd like to have a xml file with a gradient created by xml code and to also put my logo, which is an image, also on it and use it on every page.

So When I edit my background xml file, it changes on every page. If I make an adjustment on the logo that it will also change on every page. Seems like I can't add an image..

Comment: Do you know any designing software.? so you can make easily that type of image with gradient. and you can put it on any where.

Comment: Yeah I can work with photoshop and illustrator, but that's the point I don't want to use images for the gradients if I can create it in xml. I think my method will also be better for supporting different screensizes, not?

Comment: Okay what UI you have used for the Image.. ImageView?

Comment: You have make the shape layout in drawable folder.. right? and the Imageview in the layout/main..xml folder... right..? Am I right..?

Comment: No Both are in 1 file, in the drawable folder. When I change the file it changes in every page. I don't want to change the logo on every page, should the logo change

Comment: Try these code.. I have updated.. If it is helpfully than VotesUp and click on the right..

Comment: So I define in my other xml files android:background="@drawable/main" 
To get the gradient and the image on all my other files?

Comment: It doesn't work, the app crashes if I define main.xml as background for my other xml files...

Comment: You have to set the gradient.xml file do not set the main.xml in background.

Comment: Yeah then I'll have only the gradient defined on every page and I'll have to add the logo myself on every page. But I don't want that, I want to create the file once and define the logo AND the gradient so I just need to set the bg. Understand what I mean?

Comment: its not possible. You have to write these relative layout in any .xml file where you want it..